# How to store image in database captured through Web Cam using Silverlight Interface in MVC

Tags: silverlight, image, barcode

i am working on Barcode Project.In this, i am capturing image using web cam in MVC Framework
using Silverlight Interface.
In this i want to store image in database to retrieve for future use like to get barcode from the Barcode image.(To Decode).

pls help how can i store images on the server.

Thanks..................

Answer (score 1):

Hi
You must send captured image to database with [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) or [WCF RIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) service.
Than you can store image in database.
On [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Store_images_in_SQL_Serve.aspx) article from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com) you can find how to store data on database.
This article is for WinForm application but will work in your case as well.